# How to launch a new window in Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to develop a Extension for Google Chrome, but I have some problems, I want to launch or create a new window when user click on it in the icon.

Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeNzw.png
[image]

Thanks so much!

Comment: Note that your example shows a title bar. In case someone wants to remove the title bar, it is currently impossible to do this in Web Extensions.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

First off, if you have a `default_popup` defined in the manifest - you need to remove it, as it interferes with the click event you want to catch.

Then, you need to catch the event in a background script:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  // ...
});
```

Next, if we want a window, we probably want to look at the [`windows` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows). `create()` sounds like what you need:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.windows.create({/* options */});
});
```

What options do you need? Assuming you want to open a page from your extension, you'll need an URL wrapped in a `chrome.runtime.getURL`:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.windows.create({
    // Just use the full URL if you need to open an external page
    url: chrome.runtime.getURL("mypage.html")
  });
});
```

Then, to show a window like you're showing, without top toolbar, you need a window type `"popup"`:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.windows.create({
    url: chrome.runtime.getURL("mypage.html"),
    type: "popup"
  });
});
```

Finally, if you want to do something after the window has opened, use the callback:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.windows.create({
    url: chrome.runtime.getURL("mypage.html"),
    type: "popup"
  }, function(win) {
    // win represents the Window object from windows API
    // Do something after opening
  });
});
```

Comment: How could be the manifest file? I have this one:

{
  "name": "Example DOM",
  "version": "1.31",
  "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": ["tabs"],
  "browser_action": {
    "name": "Example",
    "icons": ["icon.png"],
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [ {
    "js": [ "jquery.min.js", "background.js" ],
    "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
  }]
}

Comment: Where can I put the event in order to capture the click event?

Comment: Thanks so much Mr. Xan, you really help me, also I the solution was here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/tabs/inspector.zip

Comment: The inspector example now generates error messages.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to open a new tab instead so I used `chrome.tabs.create` instead of `chrome.windows.create` :)

Comment: i was using my extension as a popup. but after i changed it to windows, I'm getting the error "Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist." in extension inspetor. looks like the connection to contentScript.js is broken. any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab)
{
    chrome.windows.create({ url: chrome.runtime.getURL("popup.html"), type: 
    "popup" });
});
```

manifest.json

```
{  
    "manifest_version": 2,  
    "name": "",  
    "description": "",  
    "version": "1.0", 

    "chrome_url_overrides": {
        "newtab": "popup.html" //the html to show in popup
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "img/zi.png" //some icon
    },

    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ],

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't need to include the "chrome_url_overrides", what that does it opens the popup.html in every new tab in chrome. Which is not desirable. Manifest V3 has all sorts of chnages too. For. eg. "browser.actions" is now just "actions" etc. Google isn't making it easier for devs with their documentation with v2 vs the new v3 manisfest changes. Its all here andf there. I wish they had a unified docs where we can select v2 docs 'vs' the v3 docs in the same website. They do have V3 docs but we have to fogure out some stuffs based on the changes compared to manifest v2

Comment: Good addition with manifest v3

Answer (score 0):

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(tab => {
  chrome.windows.create({
    url: chrome.runtime.getURL("index.html"),
    type: "popup" //No Address bar
    //In here you can also add constrain for the window
    //This is for manifest v3
  })
});
```