# How to launch a new window in Google Chrome Manifest Version 3 Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I am writing a [Manifest Version 3](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/) extension for Google Chrome. I need to open a new window in response to clicking on the extension icon in the toolbar.

[How to launch a new window in Google Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28799892/how-to-launch-a-new-window-in-google-chrome-extension) provides an answer to this question for Manifest Version 2 but I have not found an answer for [Manifest Version 3](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/).

Comment: Replace `browserAction` and `browser_action` with `action` in that answer and it's MV3.

Answer (score 0):

```
const url = "https://yourURL.com";
chrome.tabs.create({url, active:true});
```